# send dataset tables to sql? vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've seen a few questions like this asked but can't seem to find a good solution.  Let's say I have a dataset with 20 tables (all with same schema just different row data).  I have a stored procedure to populate a single sql table with the data from these tables but currently the only way I've been able to do this is to iterate through the tables in the dataset and send to sql via the stored prodcedure one at a time until all of them have made it to the target table on sql.

Is there a way to do this without iterating through each table in the dataset but still using a stored procedure?

Comment: I think you are a bit missed, read about DataTable.Merge

Comment: Not sure what "a bit missed" means but ...  you are saying still iterate through the tables but merge them all together, then send the final table via the stored procedure.   I guess that would work.  Thanks.